# Ajax error when installing

Tags: 7, installation

When installing Drupal 7.31 in the first page, I can't install with the following error message.

> An  AJAX HTTP error occurred,HTTP Result code 2: debugging information
>   follow,  Path:htp://localhost/install.php?
>   profile_standard&locale-en&op_do statustext: Unknown ResponseText:
>
> error page show : Fatal error:call to  undefined function
>   node_types_rebuild() in C:/APM_setup/htdoc/includes/common.inc  on
>   line 7512
>
> line 7511---entity_info_cache_clear();
>           7512---node_types_rebuild();
>          7513---//node_menu()  defines menu items based on node types so it needs to come
>          7514---//after node types are rebuilt.
>          7515---menu_rebuild();

Every time i delete and again try to install this always it's same.

Comment: Are you sure you've downloaded all sources? It seems there are files missing. Is the file modules/node/node.module present?

Comment: thank you your attention,,  i confirmed node.module file normal

Comment: __please__ install the latest version.

Comment: i now installed drupal7.34version and  error message is a bit changed.. 7475>>7512

Answer (score 0):

I had problem like this. You need to increase memory_limit.

**For XAMPP:** you can change it globaly in php.ini (in xampp located in '\xampp\php\php.ini')

> memory_limit = 8M // search for this "memory_limit" and adjust it by your needs (min 64M)

**For WAMP:** right click on the WAMP icon, then navigating to the PHP folder/menu-thingy and selecting php.ini, and find memory_limit (like on XAMPP)

After you made a change restart Apache and try to install Drupal from the beginning.